# why Inject an operation need latest block?

Tags: protocol, offline

Can I do without using the latest block? Because I want to do offline signing. Could I perhaps sign with the latest known block instead of the latest?

Comment: now i want to do ---  construct a operation----offline sign----broadcast it. construct a operation i following https://medium.com/@bakenrolls/sending-multiple-transactions-in-one-batch-using-tezos-rpc-6cab3a21f254 this.   offline sign used https://github.com/yugasun/tezos-sign.   but i can't broadcast. is "latest block " cause this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hash of the last known block head as branch. But it need to be injected within 64 blocks. This is to protect the operation from being executed on an alternative head (fork).

Comment: And 64 blocks means you have a bit more than 1 hour to sign the block offline and come back online